# How to understand the use of constant $c$ in the equation of $f(n) \leqslant cg(n)$ in Asymptotic notation?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

> How to understand the use of constant $c$ in the equation of $f(n) \leqslant cg(n)$ in Asymptotic notation?

*Definition:* $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if for some real constants $c\,(c > 0)$ and $n_0$, we have $f(n) \leqslant cg(n)$ for every input size $n\,(n > n_0).$

Here, I have only one confusion if we have to find $n_0$ which is kind of a threshold from where $f(n)$ is always smaller or equal than $cg(n)$ so my question is what $c$ is doing here? I mean why do we need to multiply c into $n_0$ in order to solve this problem. Is there any math concept that I miss here, can anybody help me to resolve my confusion?

Answer (score 1):

For example, we want to say that $f(n) = 2n^2+1$ is $O(n^2)$.

This is true under the current definition because for all $n \ge 1$, $f(n) \le 3n^2$. Here, $n_0=1$ and $c=3$.

There's other choices of $n_0$ and $c$ that would work. For example, for all $n \ge 10$, $f(n) \le 2.01 n^2$. Here,  $n_0 = 10$ and $c=2.01$.

However, there's  not going to be any $n_0$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$, $2n^2+1 \le n^2$. So we need the $c$.